# Ubuntu 15.10 Adapter

Tags: drivers, 15.10, iwlwifi

yesterday i installed ubuntu 15.10 on my pc (only ubuntu,not dualboot),everything was ok except that i couldnt connect to the internet,my pc doesnt have a network adapter installed so im using an external one*
Im new on ubuntu so i couldnt really find an executable driver file ,is there a solution?

pc :Memory 4GB
    processor intel core 2 quad cpu q9300 @2.50 ghz x4
    Graphics Gallium 0.4 on nv94
    os type 32-bit
    I know that these^ are not necessary but i dont know ,you might need it

Wifi Adapter :TP-LINK AC600 T2UH

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Original Source of this answer : [Steps to build driver from sources](http://hprath.com/2014/06/cisco-linksys-ae6000-ac580-media-tek-mt7610u-mt7630u-mt7650u-linux-x64-driver-patch/)

(Including the essential parts of the answer just in case if the source link changes)

- Download the driver from [here](http://www.tp-link.com/res/down/soft/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909.zip)

> Steps:
>
> 1. Unplug Wifi dongle from USB
> 2. update your sources and upgrade if any      sudo apt-get update     sudo apt-get upgrade
> 3. install gnu compiler collection     sudo apt-get install build-essential
> 4. lets install git
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install git
>    ```
> 5. get sources
>
>    ```
>    git clone https://sanrath@bitbucket.org/sanrath/mediatek_mt7610u_sta_driver_linux-64bit.git
>    ```
>
>    - if you have cloned already
>
>      ```
>      cd mediatek_mt7610u_sta_driver_linux-64bit    git pull
>      ```
> 6. build driver
>
>    ```
>    cd mediatek_mt7610u_sta_driver_linux-64bit    
>    make clean
>    make
>    sudo make install
>    ```
>
>    There should not be any errors in last commands
> 7. After the last command connect your USB Wifi adapter to any USB port. Now it must have listed all visible wifi signals(SSIDs). Connect
>      to internet
> 8. open a browser and test internet !!

Comment: Thanks a Lot! Had some errors though but i did a little research an got through them!